# Converting Date format in CAML query in Nintex workflow

Tags: datetime, caml, nintex-workflow

I am facing problems with date format in Nintex workflow with CAML query.The issue is If I use date as `2015-06-15`, my workflow is works. If I replace the same with `<Today OffsetDays="-1"/>` the query is not returning any result. 
I have the date column in the following format `6/15/2015 06:00 AM`

Please help in acheiving this in CAML query.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheieved using "Calculate Date" action. we can get the previous date and uing inline function Format Date, date can be formated.

```
fn-format({WorkflowVaribale:Date},yyyy-MM-dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

try Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(YourDate);